# Different Prefab for each new connected client?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-mirror

Trying to make it so that the second player joining the server would receive different prefab.
This is what I believed would do the job:

```
public class CustomNetwork : NetworkManager
{
    public Transform player1Position;
    public Transform player2Position;
    public GameObject player1Prefab;
    public GameObject player2Prefab;

    public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        if (numPlayers == 0)
        {
            Transform start1 = player1Position;
            GameObject player1 = Instantiate(player1Prefab, start1.position, start1.rotation);
            NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, player1);
        }
        else
        {
            Transform start2 = player2Position;
            GameObject player2 = Instantiate(player2Prefab, start2.position, start2.rotation);
            NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, player2);
        }
    }
}
```

But as result i can see 2 different player in the host client (and can move the player 1), but on the connected client I see 0 players, not mine and not the host.

This is the error I recieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error say, you need to reference both prefabs in your NetworkManager (spawnPrefabs).